# Таймер на PHP как реализовать?

Tags: php, таймер

Я хочу создать функцию, которая будет **запрещать флудить**, то есть, чтобы можно было писать сообщение раз в 5 секунд, к примеру. Хочу понять сам принцип, а не попросить вас решить мою конкретную проблему.

Например функция отправки сообщения выглядит так:

```
function sendMessage($User, $Message) 
{
    if( validate_spam() < 5000 ) { /* Если в функция возвращает меньше число чем 5 секунд */
        return json_encode(["error"=>"Прекратите флудить"]);
    } else {
        validate_spam(0) // Это, типа, что-то вроде запуска таймера
    }
}
```

То как должна выглядеть `function validate_spam($param)`
?

Comment: У сообщения должна быть `date` отправки - просто прибавляем к ней 5(5000 миллисекунд) секунд, и сверяем с текущей датой `date > time()` равно=флуд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Принцип такой:

1. Вы должны проверять когда было добавлено последнее сообщение
2. Нужно расчитать разницу в секундах между посленим добавленым сообщением и сейчас. Это можно примерно так делать: `time() - $row['last_time_message']`
3. если результат будет например 6 секунд - всё ок, добавляем сообщение в БД с текущей меткой времени, есдт результат например 4 секунды - флуд

Comment: А как вы думаете, может лучше реализовать через куки или через сессию?

Comment: куки точно не вариант, их можно чистить в браузере

Comment: @RomanKashirov лучше во время добавления нового сообщения проверять в базе, когда было оставлено последнее..... Если меньше 5 секунд прошло, то не добавлять его и просто выводить ждите.... И никакие куки и сессии не нужны